# "Fields" preceded by list of adjectives or nouns

Tags: nouns, adjectives

My friend and I are having a discussion about which of the following sentences is correct.

```
They work in the medical, governmental, environmental, and economical fields.

They work in the health, government, environment, and business fields.
```

Could you help me by telling me if at least one of the sentences is correct and why?

What do you feel would sound more natural to an American speaker?

EDIT: modified the first sentence with *economical* instead of *economic*

Comment: What makes you think that either one of the is not "correct"?

Comment: The only reason I can imagine for any of the adjectives in these two sentences to be incorrect would be that they don't correspond to the fields in which the subjects of the sentences ("they") work. Without knowing what those people do, it's not possible to answer the question.

Comment: Adjectives modify nouns, but nouns can also modify nouns. The latter is used especially when there is not a common corresponding adjective, or the apparent adjective does not refer to the profession. Example: “Healthy” is an adjective but does not refer to healthcare professions. In your lists, medical or healthcare are both used. Economics is a field of study and theory, not the adjective corresponding to business. Economic is not used; economical is a word but does not refer to the profession or academic fields of business or economics.

Comment: Thank you all. So would any of the two sentences sound more natural to an American speaker? 
I also changed "economic" to "economical" (that was an error out of the scope of the question, but many thanks)